# Bootstrap accordion/collapsible not working with ul/li navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

Im using latest bootstrap, and accordion is not working at all.. I mean, when i open Test 1 with nested 'ul', it toggles, but then when i click on test 2 with another nested 'ul', it toggles also,but without closing test 1...

Any one can help me ? It looks like it wont work with 'ul' and 'li' (without panel class).

Thanks in advance.

p.s. Here is the complete code of my accordion try.. Everything is working except auto closing previous opened.

http://jsbin.com/OKOjUlu/1/edit?html,output

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Proizvodi</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="accordion1">
            <li> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#firstLink">Test12</a>

                <ul id="firstLink" class="collapse">
                    <li>SubTest1</li>
                    <li>SubTest1</li>
                    <li>SubTest1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#secondLink">Test2</a>

                <ul id="secondLink" class="collapse">
                    <li>SubTest2</li>
                    <li>SubTest2</li>
                    <li>SubTest2</li>
                    <li>SubTest2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Test1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Test1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at jsbin.com link i have posted.. There is my code mate

Comment: fiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Kj6Ah/1/

Comment: Arun P Johny, this is still not working... Test 1 is not closing after u press test 2...

Answer (score 19):

Bootstrap mostly thrives on adding/removing css classes and its rules. So the structure needs to be the same for it to have the effect to happen same as that of div. What you missed was `<li class="panel">` on the leaf li's that holds the trigger and its respective menu. And in your case you were missing them.

BS Code:

```
//In the below line this is supposed to fetch the active elements 
//but in your case it did not match anything hence it failed to fetch active elements to make it inactive.
var actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('> .panel > .in')

    if (actives && actives.length) {
      var hasData = actives.data('bs.collapse')
      if (hasData && hasData.transitioning) return
      actives.collapse('hide')
      hasData || actives.data('bs.collapse', null)
    }
```

So Try:

```
         <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="accordion1">
            <li class="panel"> 
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#firstLink">Test12</a>
              <ul id="firstLink" class="collapse panel-collapse in">
                    <li>SubTest1</li>
                    <li>SubTest1</li>
                    <li>SubTest1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="panel"> 
               <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#secondLink">Test2</a>
               <ul id="secondLink" class="collapse panel-collapse">
                    <li>SubTest2</li>
                    <li>SubTest2</li>
                    <li>SubTest2</li>
                    <li>SubTest2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And since this was designed to be used with `div` you will have to override some rules specifically for `li`, like the one below.

```
#accordion1 li.panel{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ApmRQ/)**

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST !!!!! Can you believe me... I have tried ALMOST everything, except this.. Thank you mate. Thank you very very very much!

Comment: @user2830444 To be frank even i was wondering why it did not work with li, but then realized this was specifically designed for a div kinda design, but debugging BS js code helped me figure out what was missing. But if you see even with the css you will have to override some rules for ul/li design.

Comment: I already did it (overriding rules).. It looks just like i wanted to look. Thanks to you mate... I cant express how much grateful i am now !

Comment: @user2830444 if you ever come back, please mark this answer as correct so others know it helped!

Comment: this is not working for me.. I'm using bootstrap 4 .. Can someone help me about this

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**html:**

```
<div class="bs-example">
<div id="myAccordion" class="accordion">
 <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#myAccordion" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">Test12</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseOne">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <ul>
                  <li>SubTest1</li>
                  <li>SubTest1</li>
                 <li>SubTest1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Check here: [**Demo**](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion)

Comment: I can make it to work with divs... I need it to work with 'ul' and 'li' hierarchy.. :(